# Script cant take the info from "open" cmd to read file

Tags: python-3.x, readfile

this is my code:

```
file1 = open('input_file1', 'r') # to read input_file1
file2 = open('input_file2', 'r') # to read input_file2
    
file3 = "output.txt"    # the file include output
writeOut = open(file3,'w')

lines1=file1.readlines()  # read all lines in file 1
lines2=file2.readlines()  # read all lines in file 2

for line1 in lines1:     # line1 is a list with each item representing a line of lines1
    x = line1.split()    # separate line into many column
for line2 in lines2:     # line2 is a list with each item represent for a line of line2
    y = line2.split()    # separate line into many column

for x[1] in line1:       # with any line of file 1
    for y[2] in line2:   # do with any line of file 2 
        if (x[1] in line1 == y[2] in line2):   # if the word of column 2 of file 1 matches word of column 2 of file 2 
            writeOut.write(line1.lines1) # then write out it to the output file.

writeOut.close()
file1.close()
file2.close()
```

I dont know why my output.txt is empty.
Is my code wrong, please help me to point the mistake.
Thank you!

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  You're not actually modifying the elements of `lines1` and `lines2`.  You're taking each element, forming a new thing by calling `split`, and then assigning that new thing to either `x` or `y` which doesn't matter because you overwrite said variable in the next iteration anyway.

Comment: I'm actually surprised that `for x[1] in line1:` is even valid syntax.

Comment: I think you've made a good start, and you're actually pretty close. My advice about debugging: (1) Print stuff to the screen, instead of a file, so you can see what you're getting. (2) Print out the current value of whatever you're looping over. E.g. if you say `for a in l: ...` then print `a` within the loop, again so you can see what's going on. (3) Before an `if` statement, print something about the Boolean condition. E.g. `if a == b and c == d: ...` then before that, print the values of a, b, c, and d, and also the values of a == b and c == d. Hope this helps.